# find -exec with a variable containing a codesign command with quotes

Tags: bash, find, exec, sign, codesign

I'm struggling to make find -exec accept my variable which contains a command with quotes...

```
signpath="codesign --force --deep --verbose --sign \"My Sign ID\""
```

Then no matter what version of find I try, I cannot succeed to exec the $signpath properly:

```
find "$pathtoframeworks" -type f -not -name '*.*' -exec "$signpath {}" \;
#the above results in codesign --force --deep --verbose --sign "My Sign ID" My App.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Versions/5/MyFramework: No such file or directory

find "$pathtoframeworks" -type f -not -name '*.*' -exec $signpath "{}" \;
#the above results in "My: no identity found

find "$pathtoframeworks" -type f -not -name '*.*' -exec "$signpath" {} \;
#the above results in codesign --force --deep --verbose --sign "My Sign ID": No such file or directory
```

find -exec seems to have trouble dealing with quotes within variables... What can I do ? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting it separately:

```
find "$pathtoframeworks" -type f -not -name '*.*' -exec "$signpath" '{}' \;
```

Though better and safer is to save command line in an array:

```
signpath=(codesign --force --deep --verbose --sign "My Sign ID")
```

And use it as:

```
find "$pathtoframeworks" -type f -not -name '*.*' -exec "${signpath[@]}" '{}' \;
```

Comment: The array version should work. Escaped quotes won't work, because `-exec` doesn't use a shell to execute the command, so quotes aren't processed.

Comment: @user3767622: Does `codesign --force --deep --verbose --sign "My Sign ID" 'My App.app/Contents/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/Versions/5/MyFramework'` command work directly from command line?

Comment: @anubhava yes no problem when I type it directly in the command line. But find -exec seems to have a different interpretation of it :/

Comment: ok try this: `signpath=(codesign --force --deep --verbose --sign "My Sign ID"); find "$pathtoframeworks" -type f -not -name '*.*' -print0 | xargs -0 "${signpath[@]}"`

Comment: actually the other one with -exec and the array works as well, I misspelled a line